# How to open terminal from Mathematica

Tags: external-calls

I am currently trying to open a terminal in Linux from Mathematica in which the present working directory is given by the `Directory[]`.

My naive attempt

```
RunProcess[{"gnome-terminal", "--working-directory=" <> Directory[]}]
```

does not seem to work and returns a standard error "error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment". 
I am aware that this might not be a Mathematica specific problem but general answers regarding the same error message did nothelp me much so far.

Comment: if you have `xterm` you may be better off to just run that (or any other plain terminal). Gnome in general seems to just make simple things difficult.

Comment: FWIW, `RunProcess[{"open", "-a", "Terminal"}]` works on MacOS.

Comment: Does `RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, 
 "gnome-terminal --working-directory=" <> Directory[]]` work

Comment: @SubaThomas Unfortunately, no. It seems that the problem is really system-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
   RunProcess @ {$SystemShell,"-c",
      StringTemplate["gnome-terminal  -- /bin/bash -c 'cd `dir`; exec /bin/bash'"] @
        <|"dir" -> Directory[]|>}
```

Comment: I don't have `gnome-terminal` but `xfce4-terminal`. The solution seems to depend on the Linux-flavour. I found no environment variable telling me that `xfce4-terminal` is the right candidate. In other cases it will be `gnome-terminal` or something else. `$TERM` is not the right thing: 1st using it requires an operational `bash` and 2nd it returns `xterm-256color` in my case, which is only an indication that the virtual terminal is capable of colour output.

Comment: One has to distinguish between `RunProcess`, which runs a process in a terminal but stops the Mma session until the started process is finished and `StartProcess`, which returns a ProcessObject. `process = StartProcess @ {$SystemShell, "-c", "xfce4-terminal"}` opens a terminal window. A subsequent `WriteLine[process, "echo hello world"];` however does not write that to this terminal window as I would have expected, nor does it execute that command. - I want to run several programs and tee their output to a file parallel to showing it the terminal. *Any idea?*